# Where can I download minimal example template?

Tags: templates, format-files, minimal

Anyone have the link to download the template?
I saw it in a forum, but I don’t remember where.
I lost that files. :(

Sorry if my grammar is not the best. I’m from Mexico. Some years ago I found a template here or in Share LaTeX, but that page doesn’t exist anymore. It came with 4 *.pdf files. But the SSD where I keep it is broken and it can’t be recovered. I remember than it’s a package or a document class than I  installed manually.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A minimal working example can start as simple as `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
text
\end{document}`. What else to add (packages / contents) depends entirely on the purpose and what output or error you want to recreate. I therefore doubt that there is a useful and generally applicable "minimal example template".

Comment: Maybe you can clarify your question by providing some background information on the purpose of such a template and on what you would currently need it for.

Comment: @leandriis  I thought than it is a template because when I found it, it came with 4 or five *.pdf.

Comment: the question as written can't really be answered, the minimal latex document is just one line as @leandriis shows, there is no single link that refers to such a thing.  What do you actually want to do?

Comment: do you mean the mwe package that comes with things like `example-image.pdf` ?  You should have that already in your tex distribution or as for all packages it is on ctan at https://ctan.org/pkg/mwe

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Sorry if my grammar is not the best. I’m from Mexico. Some years ago I found a template here or in Share LaTeX, but that page doesn’t exist anymore. It came with 4 *.pdf files. But the SSD where I keep it is broken and it can’t be recovered. I remember than it’s a package or a documentclass than I  installed manually.

Comment: @TURMNIARIUS your english grammar is fine, but a "template" is not a defined thing in latex it just means some example document. So your question says basically "I once saw a link to an example latex document on the internet, what is the link?"  There are several million such links, how can we guess which you want????

Comment: forget about the file you had, what do you want to do _now_ if you said what you wanted to do someone would suggest an example to get you started. The question as it is written now has no possible answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Sorry, thanks for the info. :,(

Comment: Since you know the link (but nothing is there anymore) you can go to the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/web.php), paste the link, and search based on roughly when you saw the file. The Wayback machine is a digital archive of the internet. It has a snapshot of each site for various dates.